# SSRS report reverts back to parameter screen when you click Apply after entering parameters

Tags: reporting-services, parameters

I made a simple report that works in the designer but if you try to run it in a browser it reverts back to the parameter prompt after entering parameters and clicking Apply.  I don't get any errors and like I said, it runs in the designer.

Comment: Could you attach some screen shots?

Comment: You said, _"after entering parameters and clicking **Apply**"_ .   Did you actually mean to say _"after entering parameters and clicking **View Report**"_ ???

Comment: In the editor it shows as View Report but we have our reports hosted in SharePoint.  The reports there show Apply.

Comment: I'm not sure how to post a screen shot.  I don't see anyplace to do it.